# show only params in url: Yii url rewriting

Tags: yii, url-rewriting, yii-url-manager

I have been trying the following rule to remove all three 'module name' ,'controller', 'action' and showing only params instead, in yii:

```
'/<country:\w+>/<trip:\w+>/<poi:\w+>' => 'module/detail/index/'
```

It works fine. But whenever url from other module like 'other-module/controller/action' is called, rule is activated. Is there anyway to implement the rule inside a module or for one module only?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you need to write another rule *before* this one so that other urls match the other rule first and don't get matched by this one. The order in which you declare rules matters in Yii; if multiple rules match an URL, the first one found will be used.

Answer (score 1):

Your url rule is too broad and could apply to a lot of url path.

For me the best way to solve the problem would be to create a custom [url rule class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-custom-url-rule-classes) that check if the `<country:\w+>` is matching a country name (it could be matching one from an array or from your db if you have a table with all the countries).

Check the [yii guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-custom-url-rule-classes), they are kind of doing the same with cars brands

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask some help if you need it. I've already done it on a website.

Comment: I have one more query, I hope you won't mind it. How can I show only params name but not value in url? is it possible?

Comment: Could u give an example of what u want?

Comment: I will have country/someTitle/someTitle/ and want to have corresponding value of title so that I can process it. ie. title=myTitle but want to show only title and need to get value of title, which is myTitle. Means showing only Name in url but want to get value in action.

Comment: Then in your custom rule you can check it and get the corresponding id!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use some static string in the URL to distinguish it in that case. Dynamic URL will cause the issue, it will not allow you to call a particular module keeping the same structure.

You can either prefix or postfix any custom static string.

I hope that helps.